# How to get current time in milliseconds in PHP?

Tags: php, time, milliseconds

`time()` is in seconds - is there one in milliseconds?

Answer (score 659):

The **short answer** is:

```
$milliseconds = floor(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Comment: @FredrikWendt, I think you are confusing with `time()`. `microtime(true)` on the other hand returns the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch accurate to the nearest microsecond (see PHP reference). It's actually very easy to test if you run the above code in a loop and display the milliseconds.

Comment: You should take only first 13 digits, otherwise you might get a floating number in ~90%: substr(microtime(true) * 1000, 0, 13);

Comment: Shouldn't that be `microtime(true) / 1000` (division instead of mulitplication)?

Comment: @JordanLev, it should be multiplication because microtime(true) returns the Unix timestamp in *seconds* as a float.

Comment: I really like this solution. Also suitable for microbenchmarking in case it does not have to be too accurate. Helped me a lot finding the bottleneck in my software.

Comment: @user25163 You are not absolutely right. If you expect timestamp before "Mon, 31 Oct 1966 14:13:21 GMT" and after "Sat, 20 Nov 2286 17:46:39 GMT" it will be more than 13 digits

Comment: I do not like the response from this.It's: 
1.51196274127E+12

Comment: I don't think you need to round, as `microtime(true)` only returns 4 decimals (PHP v 7.1.16)?

Comment: Faster and probably precise enough for most people is (int)(microtime(true)*1000)

Comment: Not only is `(int)(microtime(true)*1000)` faster, it's also more correct; with `round` you can end up 0.5ms in the future, with a nasty effect of -1ms time difference somewhere ;-)

Comment: I have changed to floor() which indeed prevents the date from being in the future.

Answer (score 111):

Use [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php). This function returns a string separated by a space. The first part is the fractional part of seconds, the second part is the integral part. Pass in `true` to get as a number:

```
var_dump(microtime());       // string(21) "0.89115400 1283846202"
var_dump(microtime(true));   // float(1283846202.89)
```

Beware of precision loss if you use `microtime(true)`.

There is also [`gettimeofday`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettimeofday.php) that returns the microseconds part as an integer.

```
var_dump(gettimeofday());
/*
array(4) {
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1283846202)
  ["usec"]=>
  int(891199)
  ["minuteswest"]=>
  int(-60)
  ["dsttime"]=>
  int(1)
}
*/
```

Comment: So generally speaking `microtime()` equals `1000*time()`,right?

Comment: I see,there can be errors,but the error should be less than `1000`,right?

Comment: @COMer: Which variant you are talking about?

Comment: `microtime(true)` and `1000*time()`

Comment: @COMer: `1000*time()` won't give you milliseconds. `microtime(true)` returns a `float` which has 14 digits of precision. The seconds part already took 10, so that left 4 digits for the microseconds part. This should be enough since milliseconds only require 3 extra digits.

Comment: according to php documentation the `get_as_float` parameter was not available prior to version 5.0.0

Comment: I'm very impressed that you ran all 3 within a microsecond! What server specs are those? :D

Comment: When running `var_dump(microtime(true));`, my php (7.1.16) returns 4 decimals: `float(1523522152.2452)`. Possibly the last two digits were 0 in your case and therefore not shown?

Comment: @COMer: Based on other answers in this page, microtime(true) returns the timestamp since the Unix epoch in _seconds_. That said, I don't think this statement is wholly accurate though, since microtime(true) return value can have decimal digits, so it's not exactly integer seconds since the Unix epoch.

Answer (score 66):

#### Short answer:

**64 bits platforms only!**

```php
function milliseconds() {
    $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
    return intval( $mt[1] * 1E3 ) + intval( round( $mt[0] * 1E3 ) );
}
```

[ *If you are running 64 bits PHP then the constant `PHP_INT_SIZE` equals to `8`* ]

---

#### Long answer:

If you want an equilvalent function of `time()` in milliseconds first you have to consider that as `time()` returns the number of seconds elapsed since the "epoch time" (01/01/1970), the number of **milliseconds** since the "epoch time" is a big number and doesn't fit into a 32 bits integer.

The size of an integer in PHP can be 32 or 64 bits depending on platform.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except for Windows, which is always 32 bit. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

If you have 64 bits integers then you may use the following function:

```php
function milliseconds() {
    $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
    return intval( $mt[1] * 1E3 ) + intval( round( $mt[0] * 1E3 ) );
}
```

`microtime()` returns the number of seconds since the "epoch time" with precision up to microseconds with two numbers separated by space, like...

```
0.90441300 1409263371
```

The second number is the seconds (integer) while the first one is the decimal part.

The above function `milliseconds()` takes the integer part multiplied by `1000`

```
1409263371000
```

then adds the decimal part multiplied by `1000` and rounded to 0 decimals

```
1409263371904
```

Note that both `$mt[1]` and the result of `round` are casted to `int` via `intval()`. This is necessary because they are `float`s and the operation on them without casting would result in the function returning a `float` with a loss in precision.

Finally, that function is slightly more precise than

```
round(microtime(true)*1000);
```

that with a ratio of 1:10 (approx.) returns 1 more millisecond than the correct result.
This is due to the limited precision of the float type (`microtime(true)` returns a float).
Anyway if you still prefer the shorter `round(microtime(true)*1000);` I would suggest casting to `int` the result.

---

Even if it's beyond the scope of the question it's worth mentioning that if your platform supports 64 bits integers then you can also **get the current time in microseconds** without incurring in overflow.

If fact `2^63 - 1` (biggest signed integer) divided by `10^6 * 3600 * 24 * 365` (approximately the microseconds in one year) gives `292471`.

That's the same value you get with

```php
echo intdiv( PHP_INT_MAX, 1E6 * 3600 * 24 * 365 );
```

In other words, a signed 64 bits integer have room to store a timespan of over 200,000 years measured in microseconds.

You may have then

```php
function microseconds() {
    $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
    return intval( $mt[1] * 1E6 ) + intval( round( $mt[0] * 1E6 ) );
}
```

Comment: why not just:
`
function getMilliEpoch(){
    $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
    return $mt[1] . substr($mt[0], 0, 5) * 1000;
}`

Comment: Now there is a parameter for microtime function, if it is set to true, it's return the seconds and milliseconds since 1st of january in 1970, 0 hour 0 minutes 0 seconds as float. Here is an example: microtime(true) // 1553260455.7242

Comment: @kukko yes, but due to **limited precision** of the float type, calculating the number of millicesonds from microtime(true) will result in a **slightly inaccurate value**

Answer (score 49):

As other have stated, you can use [`microtime()`](http://php.net/microtime) to get millisecond precision on timestamps.

From your comments, you seem to want it as a high-precision UNIX Timestamp. Something like `DateTime.Now.Ticks` in the .NET world.

You may use the following function to do so:

```
function millitime() {
  $microtime = microtime();
  $comps = explode(' ', $microtime);

  // Note: Using a string here to prevent loss of precision
  // in case of "overflow" (PHP converts it to a double)
  return sprintf('%d%03d', $comps[1], $comps[0] * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Is not it return the server time?
In my case I see the stored time in db is my local browser time.
Suppose, my sever timezone is EST+3 and my browser time is GMT+6, While I submit a form from GMT+6 location, I see the stored time is GMT+6 time equivalent millisecond. So, What is the problem? :(

Answer (score 34):

Shortest version of string variant (32-bit compatibile):

```
$milliseconds = date_create()->format('Uv');
```

Comment: This one-liner should have more votes.

Comment: Yes, very true. Seems not only easier to read but also safer in terms of mixing up whether to divide or multiply by 1,000

Answer (score 16):

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.') . gettimeofday()['usec'];`

output:

`2016-11-19 15:12:34.346351`

Comment: This uses the same timestamp: `$t = gettimeofday(); echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.',$t['sec']) . $t['usec'];`

Comment: microseconds should be zero padded: `$timeofday=gettimeofday(); echo sprintf("%s.%06d", date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timeofday['sec']), $timeofday['usec']);`

Answer (score 14):

Use [`microtime(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) in PHP 5, or the following modification in PHP 4:

```
array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
```

A portable way to write that code would be:

```
function getMicrotime()
{
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '<'))
    {
        return array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
    }

    return microtime(true);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This works even if you are on 32-bit PHP:

```
list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());

$time_milli = $sec.substr($msec, 2, 3); // '1491536422147'
$time_micro = $sec.substr($msec, 2, 6); // '1491536422147300'
```

Note this doesn't give you integers, but strings. However this works fine in many cases, for example when building URLs for REST requests.

If you need integers, 64-bit PHP is mandatory.

Then you can reuse the above code and cast to (int):

```
list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());

// these parentheses are mandatory otherwise the precedence is wrong!
//                  ↓                        ↓
$time_milli = (int) ($sec.substr($msec, 2, 3)); // 1491536422147
$time_micro = (int) ($sec.substr($msec, 2, 6)); // 1491536422147300
```

Or you can use the good ol' one-liners:

```
$time_milli = (int) round(microtime(true) * 1000);    // 1491536422147
$time_micro = (int) round(microtime(true) * 1000000); // 1491536422147300
```

Answer (score 9):

**PHP 5.2.2 <**

```
$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"); // u : Microseconds
```

**PHP 7.0.0 < 7.1**

```
$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.v"); // v : Milliseconds
```

Comment: In php <7.1 new DateTime() microseconds are always 0 see https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
public function getTimeToMicroseconds() {
    $t = microtime(true);
    $micro = sprintf("%06d", ($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
    $d = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s.' . $micro, $t));

    return $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$timeparts = explode(" ",microtime());
$currenttime = bcadd(($timeparts[0]*1000),bcmul($timeparts[1],1000));
echo $currenttime;
```

> NOTE: PHP5 is required for this function due to the improvements with
>   microtime() and the bc math module is also required (as we’re dealing
>   with large numbers, you can check if you have the module in phpinfo).

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 6):

```
$the_date_time = new DateTime($date_string);
$the_date_time_in_ms = ($the_date_time->format('U') * 1000) +
    ($the_date_time->format('u') / 1000);
```

Comment: Is that actually like padding three zeroes to the right?

Comment: Not at all. It convert both part to milliseconds and give the sum. So it is more accurate than add zeros.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation, should work on 32bit as well.

```
function mstime(){
    $mstime = explode(' ',microtime());
    return $mstime[1].''.(int)($mstime[0]*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see real microseconds, you will need to change the `precision` setting in `php.ini` to 16.

After that, `microsecond(true)` gave me the output of `1631882476.298437`.

So I thought that I need to **divide** the remainder (`298437`) with 1000, but in fact, the remainder is `0.298437` **of a second**. So I need to **multiply** that by 1000 to get the correct result.

```
    function get_milliseconds()
    {
        $timestamp = microtime(true);
        return (int)(($timestamp - (int)$timestamp) * 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personaly use this:

```
public static function formatMicrotimestamp(DateTimeInterface $dateTime): int
{
    return (int) substr($dateTime->format('Uu'), 0, 13);
}
```

Comment: why not just `$dateTime->format('Uv')` ?

Answer (score 0):

When getting milliseconds we expect to see `3` digits:

```php
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000) % 1000; // e.g. 435
```

which is essentially an analogue of the implementation in JavaScript:

```js
var milliseconds = (new Date()).getMilliseconds(); // e.g. 435
```

Answer (score -4):

Use this:

```
function get_millis(){
  list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
  return (int) ((int) $sec * 1000 + ((float) $usec * 1000));
}
```

Bye