# Accurate way to measure execution times of php scripts

Tags: php

I want to know how many milliseconds a PHP for-loop takes to execute.

I know the structure of a generic algorithm, but no idea how to implement it in PHP:

```
Begin
init1 = timer(); // where timer() is the amount of milliseconds from midnight
the loop begin
some code
the loop end
total = timer() - init1;
End
```

Comment: You can fiddle around with swaths of microtime() statements if you need this in production, but if it's just for testing, just use [xdebug's profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) for instance. No messy code is a real plus.

Answer (score 698, accepted):

You can use the [`microtime`](http://php.net/microtime) function for this. From [the documentation](http://php.net/microtime):

> `microtime` — Return current Unix timestamp with microseconds
>
> ---
>
> If `get_as_float` is set to `TRUE`, then `microtime()` returns a float, which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch accurate to the nearest microsecond.

Example usage:

```
$start = microtime(true);
while (...) {

}
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
```

Comment: You need `microtime(true)` if you want to do calculations with the return value.

Comment: I know this is waaaaaay too late (almost 4 years), but as a comment... using these calculations (with the parameter `get_as_float` as `true`) will give you results in **seconds**, according to PHP documentation.

Comment: @AlejandroIván: no, it doesn't. get_as_float will return a FLOAT instead of a STRING so in face you can do calculations with the return value... check http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php: If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float, which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch accurate to the nearest microsecond.

Comment: @patrick and that's what I said: if `get_as_float` is `true`, `microtime()` returns the value representing the seconds...

Comment: While this is a very old post, we should refer to the fact that the float returned does contain the microseconds... Best solution is to times this by 1000... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656713/how-to-get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-php as an example..

Comment: I also suggest to use `round(microtime(true) - $start, 2)` to see only 2 digits after the comma.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Nowadays the best way to report script execution time is a single line at the end of your code: `$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];`  (More info in an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19425158/8112776).)

Comment: "For performance measurements, using hrtime() is recommended."
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php
(PHP 7 >= 7.3.0, PHP 8)

Answer (score 122):

You can use `microtime(true)` with following manners:

Put this at the start of your php file:

```
//place this before any script you want to calculate time
$time_start = microtime(true);
```

// your script code goes here

```
// do something
```

Put this at the end of your php file:

```
// Display Script End time
$time_end = microtime(true);

//dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes, otherwise seconds
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

//execution time of the script
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins';
```

It will output you result in `minutes`.

Answer (score 99):

You can use `REQUEST_TIME` from the `$_SERVER` superglobal array. [From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> `REQUEST_TIME`
>   The timestamp of the start of the request. (Available since PHP 5.1.0.)
>
> `REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT`
>   The timestamp of the start of the request, with **microsecond precision**. (Available since PHP 5.4.0.)

This way you don't need to save a timestamp at the beginning of your script. You can simply do:

```
<?php
// Do stuff
usleep(mt_rand(100, 10000));

// At the end of your script
$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];

echo "Did stuff in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

Here, `$time` would contain the time elapsed since the start of the script in seconds, with microseconds precision (eg. `1.341` for 1 second and 341 microseconds)

---

### More info:

**PHP documentation**:  [`$_SERVER` variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [`microtime` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: This is handy to know. So you could use: `$start = $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]; $myscript = microtime(true); $bootstrap = $myscript - $start; ...do stuff ...; $myscripttime = microtime(true) - $myscript;`

Comment: According to the linked documentation, `$time` will contain the difference in _seconds_, not in _microseconds_.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe To clarify, yes the result is in seconds. But with microsecond _precision_. e.g.  `1.1` equates to 1 second + 100 microseconds.

Comment: This is the best way to measure out the response time

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: You guys are confusing microseconds with miliseconds.

Answer (score 30):

Create file loadtime.php

```
<?php
class loadTime{
    private $time_start     =   0;
    private $time_end       =   0;
    private $time           =   0;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->time_start= microtime(true);
    }
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->time_end = microtime(true);
        $this->time = $this->time_end - $this->time_start;
        echo "Loaded in $this->time seconds\n";
    }
}
```

Than in the beggining of your script, after `<?php` write `include 'loadtime.php'; $loadtime=new loadTime();`

When page is loaded at the end there will be written "Loaded in x seconds"

Comment: Neat! But if you don't explicitly destroy your object, the output would appear after the closing `</html>` tag which is invalid

Comment: @gondo No, it wil be seconds (with microseconds expressed as decimal values of sceconds)

Answer (score 26):

The way I do it is by using `hrtime`, it's created for performance metrics and it is independent from system time. `hrtime` does not get affected by system time changes. `hrtime` is available since PHP 7.3.0

```
$start = hrtime(true);
sleep(5); // do something, in your case a loop
$end = hrtime(true);
$eta = $end - $start;
// convert nanoseconds to milliseconds
$eta /= 1e+6;
echo "Code block was running for $eta milliseconds";
```

Output:

`Code block was running for 5000.495206 milliseconds`

Comment: Yes this is the accurate one, i tested it using Xdebug profiling

Answer (score 22):

```
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i) {
    // do something
}
$total = microtime(true) - $start;
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a function that times execution of any piece of PHP code, much like Python's timeit module does: https://gist.github.com/flaviovs/35aab0e85852e548a60a

How to use it:

```
include('timeit.php');
const SOME_CODE = '
        strlen("foo bar");
';
$t = timeit(SOME_CODE);
print "$t[0] loops; $t[2] per loop\n";
```

Result:

```
$ php x.php 
100000 loops; 18.08us per loop
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this Gist

EDIT: timeit is now a separate, self-contained project at https://github.com/flaviovs/timeit

Answer (score 6):

See [microtime()](http://php.net/microtime).

Answer (score 5):

You have the right idea, except a more precise timing is available with the [microtime()](http://php.net/microtime) function.

If what is inside the loop is fast, it is possible that the apparent elapsed time will be zero.  If so, wrap another loop around the code and call it repeatedly.  Be sure to divide the difference by the number of iterations to get a per-once time.   I have profiled code which required 10,000,000 iterations to get consistent, reliable timing results.

Answer (score 3):

Here is very simple and short method

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
//the loop begin
//some code
//the loop end
$time_end = microtime(true);
$total_time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo $total_time; // or whatever u want to do with the time
?>
```

Comment: I think u r missing something i tested that code when i posted answer

Comment: var_dump(microtime(true));   // float(1283846202.89) thats what when you use microtime true

Comment: You can also use float in total time

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd share the function I put together. Hopefully it can save you time.

It was originally used to track timing of a text-based script, so the output is in text form. But you can easily modify it to HTML if you prefer.

It will do all the calculations for you for how much time has been spent since the start of the script and in each step. It formats all the output with 3 decimals of precision. (Down to milliseconds.)

Once you copy it to the top of your script, all you do is put the recordTime function calls after each piece you want to time.

Copy this to the top of your script file:

```
$tRecordStart = microtime(true);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
recordTime("Start");

function recordTime ($sName) {
  global $tRecordStart;
  static $tStartQ;
  $tS = microtime(true);
  $tElapsedSecs = $tS - $tRecordStart;
  $tElapsedSecsQ = $tS - $tStartQ;
  $sElapsedSecs = str_pad(number_format($tElapsedSecs, 3), 10, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $sElapsedSecsQ = number_format($tElapsedSecsQ, 3);
  echo "//".$sElapsedSecs." - ".$sName;
  if (!empty($tStartQ)) echo " In ".$sElapsedSecsQ."s";
  echo "\n";
  $tStartQ = $tS;
}
```

To track the time that passes, just do:

```
recordTime("What We Just Did")
```

For example:

```
recordTime("Something Else")
//Do really long operation.
recordTime("Really Long Operation")
//Do a short operation.
recordTime("A Short Operation")
//In a while loop.
for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i ++) {
  recordTime("Loop Cycle ".$i)
}
```

Gives output like this:

```
//     0.000 - Start
//     0.001 - Something Else In 0.001s
//    10.779 - Really Long Operation In 10.778s
//    11.986 - A Short Operation In 1.207s
//    11.987 - Loop Cycle 0 In 0.001s
//    11.987 - Loop Cycle 1 In 0.000s
...
//    12.007 - Loop Cycle 299 In 0.000s
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation that returns fractional seconds (i.e. 1.321 seconds)

```
/**
 * MICROSECOND STOPWATCH FOR PHP
 *
 * Class FnxStopwatch
 */
class FnxStopwatch
{
    /** @var float */
    private $start,
            $stop;

    public function start()
    {
        $this->start = self::microtime_float();
    }
    public function stop()
    {
        $this->stop = self::microtime_float();
    }
    public function getIntervalSeconds() : float
    {
        // NOT STARTED
        if (empty($this->start))
            return 0;
        // NOT STOPPED
        if (empty($this->stop))
            return ($this->stop - self::microtime_float());

        return $interval = $this->stop - $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * FOR MORE INFO SEE http://us.php.net/microtime
     *
     * @return float
     */
    private static function microtime_float() : float
    {
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());

        return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of ```list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);``` You can use ```return microtime(true);```

Answer (score 2):

if you like to display that time in seconds:

```
<?php

class debugTimer
{
    private $startTime;
    private $callsCounter;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->startTime = microtime(true);
        $this->callsCounter = 0;
    }

    public function getTimer(): float
    {
        $timeEnd = microtime(true);
        $time = $timeEnd - $this->startTime;
        $this->callsCounter++;
        return $time;
    }

    public function getCallsNumber(): int
    {
        return $this->callsCounter;
    }
}

$timer = new debugTimer();
usleep(100);
echo '<br />\n
    ' . $timer->getTimer() . ' seconds before call #' . $timer->getCallsNumber();

usleep(100);
echo '<br />\n
    ' . $timer->getTimer() . ' seconds before call #' . $timer->getCallsNumber();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my script to measure average time

```php
<?php

$times = [];
$nbrOfLoops = 4;
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbrOfLoops; ++$i) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    sleep(1);
    $times[] = microtime(true) - $start;
}

echo 'Average: ' . (array_sum($times) / count($times)) . 'seconds';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Randomize sleeping time
usleep(mt_rand(100, 10000));

// REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT is available in the $_SERVER superglobal array.
// It contains the timestamp of the start of the request with microsecond precision.
$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];

echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

here is the link for [this](https://www.php.net/microtime)

Answer (score -1):

You can find the execution time in second with a single function.

```
// ampersand is important thing here
function microSec( & $ms ) {
    if (\floatval( $ms ) == 0) {
        $ms = microtime( true );
    }
    else {
        $originalMs = $ms;
        $ms = 0;
        return microtime( true ) - $originalMs;
    }
}

// you don't have to define $ms variable. just function needs
// it to calculate the difference.
microSec($ms);
sleep(10);
echo microSec($ms) . " seconds"; // 10 seconds

for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    // you can use same variable everytime without assign a value
    microSec($ms);
    sleep(1);
    echo microSec($ms) . " seconds"; // 1 second
}

for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    // also you can use temp or useless variables
    microSec($xyzabc);
    sleep(1);
    echo microSec($xyzabc) . " seconds"; // 1 second
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It would be more clear this way

```
<?php

$start = hrtime(true);

while (...) {
}

$duration = hrtime(true) - $start;
echo  $duration * 1000 ." -> microseconds". PHP_EOL; 
echo  $duration * 1000000 ." -> milliseconds". PHP_EOL; 
echo  $duration * 1e6 ." -> milliseconds". PHP_EOL;
```

the result

```
37180000 -> microseconds
37180000000 -> milliseconds
37180000000 -> milliseconds
```

Comment: The time in milliseconds is equal to the time in nanoseconds divided by 1,000,000.

Comment: Surely you understand the errors here...