# PHP Program not working properly

Tags: php, networking, network-programming, localhost

I have got a strange problem.This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$fp=fopen("test.txt","w",true);
if($fp)
{
$start=time();
for($i=0;$i<=17800;$i++)
{
    fwrite($fp,"bandwith");
}
fclose($fp);
$stop=time();
$diff=round($stop-$start,2);
$fsize=round(filesize("test.txt")/1024,2);
$bandwidth=$fsize/$diff;
echo "<strong>The speed of your broadband is</strong> ".$bandwidth;
}
else
{
    echo ("problem with permission");
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am actually trying to calculate the bandwidth.The error I get is "Division by zero" on the $bandwidth calculation part.The strange part is that when I keep on refreshing the window I suddenly get the answer then again the problem comes during the next refresh.

Extra info:

I found out that the error occurs when the $start and $stop are same.Now my question is:Is localhost so damn fast to finish the text file opening and writing part within the same time resulting in division my zero error?I also checked the text file and it contains the data and it is deleted and written every other time.I just want a clear explanation of the reason behind it.

Comment: Yes.  Time() is in seconds.  A file could be read in milliseconds.

Comment: The file is not read it is written every time the script executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a more accurate time calculation, and your system supports it, you can use [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php):

```
$time_including_microseconds = microtime();
```

See the example in the manual about exploding it.

Comment: I know that.I want to know is it possible for the localhost to finish the above task of creating and writing a file in that speed of 0 seconds difference?

Comment: @user1633170 Sure, 0.49999999999... seconds before and after a whole second is a long time to write a file on the local system.

Comment: @user1633170 jeroen has a lot of rep, which indicates he's pretty reliable. Try his method.

Comment: @user1633170 By the way, you should always account for a division by zero, even when you use micro-seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to measure file access time:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question.I don't want file modification time.I am just calculating the time taken to finish the task.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, it's very likely your file operation (writing) is being completed in less than a second, resulting in the division by zero.

To accomplish your goal, considering using PHP's [microtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function. This includes milliseconds with the timestamp.

See also:
[Accurate way to measure execution times of php scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245971/accurate-way-to-measure-execution-times-of-php-scripts)