# About Wordpress theme architecture: one index.php vs. multiple template files

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Just a quick questions to all you WordPress wizards out there regarding WordPress theme architecture: what’s better in terms of performance, syntax, maintenance, etc.?

**Version A:**

One `index.php` that includes external parts (different loops and other structural) elements depending on if `is_page`, `is_archive`, `is_single`, `is_tax`, etc.

or

**Version B:**

Separate files for `index.php`, `pages.php`, `single.php`, `archive.php`, etc.

Comment: Take a look at how the templates are loaded in the source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L44

Comment: Thanks to all of you! The answers make total sense.
Just to give you more background info: in my experience, the difference between archive, single, etc. usually is just a few lines of code within the loop. But for bigger design changes I have to alter several files, if I use Version B. So I thought about trying Version A (one structural file which includes different loops). –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version B** is going to be better from a performance, as well as an organizational standpoint.

Take a look at the way template files are called to generate a WordPress page based on the WordPress Template hierarchy. This is straight from [the Codex on Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

[image]

As you can see, **index.php** is the LAST template that is looked for during a request.

Also, and perhaps more subjective, is that breaking the templates into individual files makes things easier to maintain, as you don't have one HUGE file with conditional statements. Each template does a single thing, and does that thing well.

EDIT: Well, I was hoping you'd be able to see the image...but here's the original from the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg

Comment: Marked as accepted answer because of background info and sound reasoning!

Killer argument #1: index.php is LAST template.
Killer argument #2: each template does a single thing, and does that thing well. (What a nice quote for a poster ;-))

Answer (score 1):

If our website has very similar pages then one index.php might work for you. For all other cases having code in separate files will be crucial to being able to easily manage and grow your site. The more messy the code is the more potential problems you'll get.

In terms of performance I think it won't make much of a difference. You can track it using a timer - [Accurate way to measure execution times of php scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245971/accurate-way-to-measure-execution-times-of-php-scripts)

I usually put the initial time tracker in the index.php in your root folder and then the final time tracker in the footer. This way you can easily see the difference in total execution time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gone try that!

Answer (score 0):

For me at least, version B. It's too easy for a designer a simple structure for template, and it's typical and traditional on wordpress.