# microtime(true) - Trouble measuring PHP script execution time

Tags: php, performance

While trying to compare algorithm running time in PHP, I came across the `microtime()` function. But I think there's something fundamental I've missed in understanding. The difference of two `microtime(true)` calls returns the result in seconds, right? Then consider this extremely simple script:

```
$t1 =  microtime(true);
//do nothing
$t2 = microtime(true);

echo ($t2 - $t1);
```

When I run this script several times, I get values varying between 1.19 seconds and 3.5 seconds. This is clearly wrong, as the page reload is instant and there's absolutely nothing for the script to do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!   [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245971/accurate-way-to-measure-execution-times-of-php-scripts)

Comment: @RohitGupta Okay, but I've sifted through many similar answers. My point is why it takes 1-3 seconds for the script to do nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking the script execution time in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculations (with the parameter get_as_float as true) will give you results in seconds, according to PHP documentation.

**By default, microtime() returns a string in the form "msec sec", where sec     is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (0:00:00 January 1,1970 GMT),     and msec measures microseconds that have elapsed since sec and is also     expressed in seconds.**

**If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float, which     represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch accurate to the     nearest microsecond.**

For full text refer here  http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

On top of that your OS is doing lots of things in between.

Comment: Hmm . . . I dug up a lot of official documentation, but never thought about the OS angle. Does that mean I can never have an accurate estimate of running time of a code section? It seems to me that depending on the OS, selection sort, for example, might turn out to be more efficient than quicksort sometimes! Do you agree?

Comment: His answer is now deleted, but he wrote of milliseconds, which I find nowhere in the documentation. Anyway . . .

Answer (score 4):

You must be misreading the result, which is for example:

```
2.1457672119141E-6
```

- 2.14 millionth of a second, not 2,14 seconds.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5aa27a5fa9a228fd66eb08f0bb49384fc5b840d9