# Comparing an array with a template, is a loop efficient?

Tags: php

Which is a more efficient way of comparing an array's keys with a template and filtering out empty values? Then operating on the remaining parts of the array?

```
$arr = array_intersect_key(array_filter($arr), $this->arrTemplate);
foreach ($arr as $_k => $_v) {
   //Do something
```

Or this:

```
foreach ($arr as $_k => $_v) {
        if (array_key_exists($_k, $this->arrTemplate)) {
            if (empty($_v)) {
                continue;
            }   
            //Do something     
        }
    }
```

Also as a side question, how can I measure efficiency for myself?

Comment: I think your side question is the key here: any presumption without measurement is common mistake. :) In general I wouldn't use loop where predefined php function is available.

Comment: How would I measure it?

Comment: Start timer (catch microtime stamp in a variable), perform 100 000 operations (`for` loop), subtract from current microtime stamp, print it. Than, in next script call (important, not in the current script) do that for other way. For more accurre measurment, do whole thing multiple times and calculate medium values .

Comment: For measurement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245971/accurate-way-to-measure-execution-times-of-php-scripts