# How to change specific first Letter in string to Capital using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

If the first character of my string contains any of the following letters, then I would like to change the first letter to Uppercase: (a,b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,y,z) but not (e,i,u,x).

For example,

- `luke` would become `Luke`
- `egg` would stay the same as `egg`
- `dragon` would become `Dragon`

I am trying to acheive this with PHP, here's what I have so far:

```
<?php if($str("t","t"))
 echo ucfirst($str);
  else
   echo "False";
    ?>
```

My code is simply wrong and it doesn't work and I would be really grateful for some help.

Comment: Why are you calling the string?

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: @Mark what is going on with this abandoned question?  Are you still seeking a solution?  Have your requirements changed?  Please do something to progress the status of this page.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
function ucfirstWithCond($str){
    $exclude = array('e','i','u','x');

    if(!in_array(substr($str, 0, 1), $exclude)){
        return ucfirst($str);
    }

    return $str;
}

$test = "egg";
var_dump(ucfirstWithCond($test)); //egg
$test = "luke";
var_dump(ucfirstWithCond($test)); //Luke
```

Demo:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c87c6cbf8c616dd76fe69b8f081a1fbf61cf2148

Comment: is non-regex code more efficient then? as I had not considered this. thanks

Comment: How many words you have to modify? I think it could be negligible for few words. You may also measure this for your specific case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245978/1403785

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~^(?![eiux])[a-z]~', function($m) {
    return ucfirst($m[0]);
}, $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/q9lMW)

The `^(?![eiux])[a-z]` regex matches any lowercase ASCII char at the start of the string but `e`, `u`, `i` and `x` and the letter matched is turned to upper inside the callback function to `preg_replace_callback`.

If you plan to process each *word* in a string you need to replace `^` with `\b`, or - to support hyphenated words - with `\b(?<!-)` or even with `(?<!\S)` (to require a space or start of string before the word).

Comment: This works a treat, thanks Wiktor! However, using your existing code, do you know how I would Capitalise the first words in a string which have no specified break or space in them eg. mylongstring to MyLongString?? Presumably this wouldn't be possible without some kind of code link to check a dictionary of words.

Comment: @Mark Not sure it is not possible. It actually is already a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If the first character could be other than a letter then check with an array range from `a-z` that excludes `e,i,u,x`:

```
if(in_array($str[0], array_diff(range('a','z'), ['e','i','u','x']))) {
    $str[0] = ucfirst($str[0]);
}
```

Probably simpler to just check for the excluded characters:

```
if(!in_array($str[0], ['e','i','u','x'])) {
    $str[0] = ucfirst($str[0]);
}
```