# Insert and update in same function for different table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there any way to write a insert query and update query in same function for different tables in codeigniter.

Mean to say i want to update a table and in same query i want to insert a response time in other table please show me way.

Advance thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:
Log the time before executing the update query. say it is `time1`.
Then find the difference of the time between `current system time - time1` after executing the query and insert it into desired table.

**EDIT**
Adding sample code:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

//Your query goes here

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Execution time taken  $time seconds\n";
?>
```

Comment: for more time related info see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656713/how-to-get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function insertUpdate() {
  $data = array(
        'tableindex'=>'datayouwanttoinsert',

        );
  $data1 = array(
       'tableindex'=>'datayouwanttoupdate',
      );
     $this->db->insert('databasename.dbo.tablename',$data);
     $this->db->update('databasename.dbo.tablename',$data1);

}
```

i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can't update multiple tables with one query.  You can run a second query and use the MySQL function 'NOW()' to insert the current time into a field.

INSERT INTO table (id, data, posted) VALUES(0, '12345', NOW());

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$start_time = microtime(true);
$this->db->insert('tablename1',$data);
$end_time = microtime(true);

$response_time = $time_end - $time_start;
$arrdata=array();

$arrdata['response_time']=$response_time;
 $this->db->where('id', $id);//if u have any id
$this->db->update('tablename2',$arrdata);
```