# how to convert php time() to android timestamp?

Tags: php, android

My server send file last update time as php time() string

my android app receive response from server as php timestamp like 1365228375

as i know android read timestamp in milliseconds

my question is how to convert the php time() to android timestamp and how i can convert the converted timestamp to human readable in android app ?

Comment: If you use `time()`, converting makes no sense imo. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656713/how-to-get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-php) to get the time in real ms

Comment: Hi Jack, if you found an answer useful enough to solve your problem, it would be good to tick it as _the answer_ so that future users can see which solution to work from.

Comment: No worries mate! it's why we hang around here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Java's Calendar: (since my beloved Date is deprecated)
[Calendar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Try something like:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.setTimeInMillis(1365228375*1000);

System.out.print(c.toString()); - just to demonstrate the API has lots of info about presentation
```

Just put whatever is being returned from your PHP to the Android app in place of the '1365228375' shown above.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, conversion from seconds to microseconds shouldn't be too difficult;

```
echo time() * 1000;
```

If you need the time stamp to be **acurate** in milliseconds, look at [`microtime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) however, this function does *not* return an integer so you'll have to do some conversions

Don't know how to convert that to a readable time in Android

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really an "Android" time stamp per se. [PHP:time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns a unix time stamp measured in seconds from epoch GMT/UTC. If you want to create a human readable time stamp such as `January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT` you can use Java's Calender but I would recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead as it's a lot easier to use and far more robust.