# How to convert time in milliseconds in php

Tags: php, time

I have a subtitle files in which i have start_time and end_time which is formatted like this **00:38:42,689** but i don't want this i have functionality of subtitles which work on milliseconds so i want to convert it in milliseconds in php.

How i can get it done. Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
You can split the string with ":" and then multiply each part. It should be pretty easy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current time in milliseconds in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656713/how-to-get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-php)

Comment: is your value is in correct format? i think not.

Comment: No sample code shown, so downvote stands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = "00:38:42,689";
$time   = explode(":", $string);

$hour   = $time[0] * 60 * 60 * 1000;
$minute = $time[1] * 60 * 1000;

$second = explode(",", $time[2]);
$sec    = $second[0] * 1000;
$milisec= $second[1];

$result = $hour + $minute + $sec + $milisec;

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to do the parsing and calculate from there:

```
$timeString = '00:38:42,689';
$dateTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s,u', $timeString);

$milliseconds =
    $dateTime->format('H') * 60 * 60 * 1000 +  // milliseconds in an hour
    $dateTime->format('i')      * 60 * 1000 +  // milliseconds in a minute
    $dateTime->format('s')           * 1000 +  // milliseconds in a second
    $dateTime->format('u')           / 1000;   // microseconds in a millisecond
```

Example of this code is [here](http://ideone.com/dTpKE8).