# Only get current microseconds

Tags: php

To get the microseconds **and** timestamp, I use code from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424665/1185126):

```
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

This gives the current timestamp *with* microseconds, like `1528720042358`.

How do I *only* get the microseconds part?

Comment: You did read the manual…? http://php.net/microtime

Comment: @IsThisJavascript The code above adds the current timestamp *with* microseconds. My aim is to only get the microseconds part with should be a value between `1-999`

Comment: Firstly, why in the world are people downvoting this question and the answers? Secondly, I might answer my own question here with `$time = explode('.', microtime(true)); $microsec = $time[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get just the part after the decimal point, *don't* pass [`true` as argument to `microtime`](http://php.net/microtime) and explode on a space:

```
list($msec) = explode(' ', microtime());
```

From there multiply or round the value to whatever range you need:

```
echo $msec * 1000000;
```

Comment: See the comment to my question where I went with this option: `$time = explode('.', microtime(true)); $microsec = $time[1];`

Comment: @Henrik That'll lose you precision since you're going through an intermediate float value.