# Uncaught exception 'Firebase\JWT\BeforeValidException' with message 'Cannot handle token prior to 50901-05-16T05:58:02+0000'

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, jwt

I'm understanding this has to do with a timezone difference between the library and my server.

I set my PHP scripts to use UTC timezone. I'm really not sure how to fix this problem. There doesn't seem to be too much out  there on the internet to fix the problem. I tried changing the leeway of JWT class and I'm still receiving problems. Code is posted below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

include "../../inc/dbinfo.inc";
require '../vendor/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
JWT::$leeway = 60;
?>
```

Also I've tried:

```
JWT:$leeway += 60;
```

I am using an EC2 instance from Amazon Web Services. I am also using Firebase JWT api to produce the token.

EDIT: If i'm not providing enough information, please let me know. If there's a better way to produce JWT also let me know. I'm having a lot of issues with this library atm.

EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is how I'm creating the token....

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

    $currentTimeInMillis = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

        $token = array(
            "iss" => "http://example.org",
            "sub" => $username,
            "iat" => $currentTimeInMillis,
            "exp" => $currentTimeInMillis + 256000000);

        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
```

Comment: If I add a leeway of 234325253453245 ms then I don't receive an error. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: From where does this date 50901-05-16T05:58:02+0000' came from? Seems that the server has the incorrect time.

Comment: Amazon EC2 timezone is US East

Comment: +0000 means UTC if it were for instance -0500 I would have set the timezone to EST

Comment: I know, but the year "50901" is the odd part

Comment: I honestly didn't know that was the year.... I've added how I'm creating the token. Again not sure if that is nearing the source of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
$currentTimeInMillis = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

If you run this command:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', round(microtime(true) * 1000));
```

You see `50901-06-21`, which points to your problem. Remove the round part:

```
$currentTimeInMillis = microtime(true);
```

Comment: Wow thank you Felippe. I honestly have no idea why I didn't think of that. That makes total sense. 

I got that snippet of code from a highly rated posted. Why in the world was that posted in the first place... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656713/how-to-get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-php